# Why is @Month returning day in view column populating a Date/Time field in LotusScript?

Tags: date, datetime, view, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am using LotusScript to populate a date/time field in a Lotus Notes document. Here is the code that I am using:

```
Dim dtItem As NotesItem
Set dtItem = endorsementDoc.GetFirstItem("EndorsementEffectedDate")
Dim paymentDue As NotesDateTime
Set paymentDue = dtItem.DateTimeValue
Call paymentDue.AdjustDay(45)
idoc.PaymentDue = paymentDue.DateOnly
```

The EndorsementEffectedDate field is a date/time field that is populated by the user. I want to set the PaymentDue field to 45 days after the EndorsementEffectedDate. To do this, I am using the AdjustDay method of the NotesDateTime class.

The problem is that when I set PaymentDue to paymentDue.DateOnly, the @Month formula returns the day of the month instead of the month itself. For example, if EndorsementEffectedDate is 20/04/2023 and I add 45 days, PaymentDue is set to 04/06/2023 but @Month(PaymentDue) returns 4.

The column formula for month is `@Month(@TextToTime(@Text(PaymentDue)))`

Why is @Month returning the day instead of the month? How can I get the correct month value in LotusScript?

I checked the Windows servers date/time settings and they are set correctly.

I also tried using the Format function to explicitly make the date in the format "dd/mm/yyyy" but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Month returns really the month. But you must check the date format you put in you field when:

```
idoc.PaymentDue = paymentDue.DateOnly
```

Your date format is (probably) MM/DD/YYYY : for example 04/20/2023. And 06/**04**/2023 when you add 45 days.

@Month is based on your regional settings and return 04.
Do not store your PaymentDue as a string, but as a real Date Time:

```
idoc.PaymentDue = paymentDue.LSLocalTime
```

Other possibility : your lotuscript code run on your machine with a DD/MM/YYYY format (and the PaymentDue is in this string format). But the view is calculated on the server that has a MM/DD/YYYY regional setting.

Comment: Best is to avoid storing date strings altogether... Just don't.

Comment: paymentDue.LSLocalTime worked. Thanks very much for your help Emmanuel.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to make sure that the time component is stripped from the adjusted EndorsementEffectedDate.

This line does it, but...

```
idoc.PaymentDue = paymentDue.DateOnly
```

... It is setting idoc.PaymentDue as a *text* field. As per the help for the [DateOnly method](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_DATEONLY_PROPERTY.html), it returns a string.

If you want it to be treated as a date, you should instantiate another NotesDateTime object from paymentDue.DateOnly and assign this new object to idoc.PaymentDue.

Answer (score 0):

After your lotusscript code that you show has run, are you saving the document?

E.g

```
Call iDoc.save(false, false)
```

If you are, then I think your view column may be corrupt.  Try deleting it and create a new column with the same formula.